# Will Instrumentation Key and Connection String change if we Migra classic Application Insights to workspace-based Application Insights resources

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-migrate

Will Instrumentation Key and Connection String change if we Migrate classic Application Insights to workspace-based Application Insights resources

I want to find out the impact of migrating classic Application Insights to workspace-based Application Insights resources

Answer (score 0):

No, neither Instrumentation Key nor Connection String changes during migration.

Answer (score 0):

***Keys of Classic Application Insights:***

[image]

- We require `Log Analytics Workspace` to Migrate  to`Workspace-based`.
- Create a `Log Analytics Workspace`.

[image]

- In your `Application Insights` => `Properties` => Under `WORKSPACE`  => click on `Migrate to Workspace-based`.

[image]

- Select the `Log Analytics Workspace` which you have created in the first step = >click on `Apply`.

[image]

- You can see the warning that once migrated to `Workspace-based`, again cannot migrate back to the `classic` Application Insights.
- Even I didn't find any option. We have only option to change it to another `Workspace`.

[image]

- Keys after Migrating to `Workspace-based`.

[image]

I dint find any changes in the `Instrumentation Key` and `Connection String`.

As mentioned by @ZakiMa, yes there will be no changes in the `Instrumentation` and `Connection String` Keys.

- New Key with  `WorkSpace` name is added.

[image]

> impact of migrating classic Application Insights to workspace-based Application Insights resources

Data is not transferred from classic to the Workspace-based Application Insights Instance.

As mentioned in the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#will-there-be-any-impact-on-live-metrics-or-other-monitoring-experiences),

> There will be no impact on our Live Metrics or AppInsights Monitoring.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource).